# How to hide embedded dependencies when using an OSGI bundle with maven?

Tags: java, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle, sling

Is there a way to use an OSGI bundle as a maven dependency without getting all the packages from it into the classpath that it doesn't even export?

Background of the question: We just added the [org.apache.sling.xss](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.xss/2.0.12) bundle as a maven dependency into our project. As you can see [in the pom.xml](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/sling/org.apache.sling.xss/2.0.12/org.apache.sling.xss-2.0.12.pom), it just exports the package org.apache.sling.xss but embeds various dependencies directly into it's [jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/sling/org.apache.sling.xss/2.0.12/org.apache.sling.xss-2.0.12.jar) as [Private-Package](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html). While OSGI hides this stuff from other bundles, maven does not. So we get collisions: org.apache.sling.xss embeds e.g. version 1.7.0 of commons-beanutils, which is incompatible with the newer version of commons-beanutils we have been using, so that we now get compile errors.

Is there any good solution to this - both from our perspective, as from the perspective of the maintainers of the org.apache.sling.xss bundle? Ideally, you'd get only the exported org.apache.sling.xss package into the classpath if you use that bundle. So maybe a good solution would be if org.apache.sling.xss provided a separate API jar, containing only that class? Is there a standard way to do this, or another solution? Can we somehow tell maven just to include only that package into the classpath? (I know maven has [dependency exclusion](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html), but that doesn't help here, since the problematic stuff is not a transitive dependency of sling.xss, but actually included into the org.apache.sling.xss jar.)

Comment: One way to resolve the conflict would be to include the desired version of conflicted dependency under `dependencyManagement ` in your project pom.

Comment: @awd Thank you, but that doesn't work: the dependencies aren't included transitively from sling.xss but is embedded directly into the sling.xss jar. That's not something controlled by maven.

Comment: That's one of the very bad things people doing just shading/importing other packages into their own which blocks other people from excluding them...

Comment: I think the main issue is that there is no API jar. As sling is a pretty open community I can image we can change that.

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes. Unfortunately, that seems sometimes even needed with OSGI, if you do not want / cannot deploy the dependencies as OSGI bundles. :-( But it seems the real issue here is that there is no API jar, as ChristianSchneider says.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no good way to handle such bundles with maven.

The recommended way is to split the bundle into an API bundle that just defines the API and an implementation bundle that imports the API and imports or embeds all implementation dependencies.

This way consumers will only have a maven dependency to the API and the problem does not occur at all.

Can you open an jira issue for sling xss to provide an API bundle?

Answer (score 0):

You could include in your build system a step that performs OSGi resolution, for example using the [bnd-export-maven-plugin](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/maven/bnd-export-maven-plugin).

In this way the build *as a whole* will fail if you write code that depends on a non-exported package of another bundle. This is because bnd will automatically add an `Import-Package` for the package that you used in your bundle, but the resolve step will be unable to find a corresponding `Export-Package` in the other bundle.

Of course this is not ideal. You will still be able to write the code in your IDE and compile it with the `maven-compiler-plugin`. But you at least find out about the problem before you hit the runtime.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not understand how this applies to the problem. My problem was that sling.xss contains many classes from e.g. commons.beanutils which overrode the version of common.beanutils I had in the classpath since the real common.beanutils came later. That even generated a compiletime error. I could work around that compiletime error by putting commons.beanutils before sling.xss in the pom.xml, but that's a pretty dirty solution.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStörr You're right, sorry. I didn't read your question carefully enough. The commonly asked question is something like "I used a package at compile time that is not visible at runtime, how can I make that into a compile-time error?", and I jumped to conclusions based on your first sentence.